# XPath evaluate a query and retrieve the value

Tags: php, xml, xslt, xpath

I have this code

```
$XMLTranslationObject = new DOMDocument();
$XMLTranslationObject->load("../xdata/xml/translation/en-US/profile.xml");

$Xpath = new DOMXpath($XMLTranslationObject);
$Result = $Xpath->evaluate("Field[@Name = 'AttachedFiles']")->nodeValue;

echo $Result;
```

and the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Translation language="en-US">

    <!-- Basic Begin -->
        <Field Name="SiteName">Brainfavor</Field>
        <Field Name="Error">Error</Field>
    <!-- Basic End -->

    <!-- Header Begin -->
        <Field Name="Name">Name</Field>
        <Field Name="WorkingAt">Working at</Field>
        <Field Name="Phone">Phone</Field>
```

witch gives me the following error

Notice: Undefined property: DOMNodeList::$nodeValue in C:\xampp\htdocs\brainbook\profile\loadmore.php on line 30

All i want is to retrieve the value of a row where field name is `AttachedFiles` , just run a simple Xpath query and retrieve the result. Using XSLT it is easy

```
<xsl:value-of select="$TranslationProfile/Field[@Name = 'AttachedFiles']"/>
```

but i didn't used PHP Xpath before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct formulation is

```
$Xpath->evaluate("string(Field[@Name = 'AttachedFiles'])");
```

This works because the [`string`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256133.aspx) function converts the node set (which actually would consist of just one node in this case) to the value the first node in the set.

Warning: this means that if there are multiple elements that match the query only the first one (in document order) will have its value returned.

Comment: This works, thanks, but isn't that true that `$Xpath->evaluate("string(Field[@Name = 'AttachedFiles'])");` == `$Xpath->evaluate("Field[@Name = 'AttachedFiles']")-nodeValue;` ? the `string` is the only way?

Comment: @Empeus: No, you can do without `string` but in that case `evaluate` returns a [`DOMNodeList`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php) which you have to iterate over. You can access `nodeValue` on each node in the list, but not on the list itself.